# How to change the path of temp file,redo log file when restore an rman backup on another machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman

I am trying to migrate my database (*11.2.0.4*) A to another machine by using rman backup. At present, in the source machine, the redo log file, temp file is stored under the directory foo (`/foo`). In the target machine, I would like to store these files under the directory bar (`/bar`).
In the past practice, what I did is to create foo for these files and move these files to bar manually after the recovery is complete. RMAN is such a powerful tool that I think there must be some an easy way to satisfy my requirement.
So far, by searching the google, I got a useful rman command for temp file:

```
set newname for tempfile <fileno> to '<path>'
```

It seems that there is no similar command for redo file.
Before using this command to perform a recovery, I have several questions to ask:

1. When we take an full backup, the backup did not go with temp tablespace and redo files, but in the past migration I experienced, I found that when I open (`alter database open resetlogs`)the database after recovery is complete, redo log files and temp files exist. Will rman create this automatically for database? I can`t find the reliable oracle documents for this topic.
2. To change the path for redo is so boring, I would the finish this task in the rman scripts, is there any command available to rename the redo log file in the rman scripts?

Comment: Temp tablespace and online redo logs files will be created on the basis of information available in control file. For each online redo log that is to be created at a different location than it had on the source host, use  `ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE` commands to specify the path name on the destination host. [More...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmadvre.htm#BRADV89833)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a pfile and set the following in the pfile, or you can use an spfile and do a startup nomount to set the following variables. You can have as many directories as you want the pattern will still be: '','','','','',''...

```
alter system set db_file_name_convert='/foo/','/bar/' scope=spfile;
alter system set log_file_name_convert='/foo/','/bar/' scope=spfile;
```

You can also specify the redo on the clone/restore command.

```
DUPLICATE DATABASE TO mytest BACKUP LOCATION '/mybackup/mytest' 
LOGFILE 
       GROUP 1 ('/mybackup/mytest/redo01a.log',  '/mybackup/mytest/redo01b.log') SIZE 256M REUSE,
       GROUP 2 ('/mybackup/mytest/redo02a.log',  '/mybackup/mytest/redo02b.log') SIZE 256M REUSE,
       GROUP 3 ('/mybackup/mytest/redo03a.log',  '/mybackup/mytest/redo03b.log') SIZE 256M REUSE  
NOFILENAMECHECK;
```

Comment: db_file_name_convert and log_file_name_convert is for data guard mainly,I did not try these parameters before,what about you ?Does it work when doing rman recovery?

Comment: I have used the parameters for restore and clone and it works. I also added the part about redo after I initially posted my reply.

Comment: what about the first question?

Comment: for this post http://oratin.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-recover-droped-tablespace.html, when using RESTORE command to restore a database into new host even if we use the “DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT” & “LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT” parameters to change the file names it will not take effect as we do the restore step by step

Comment: The convert parameters don't affect the control files. Those are set in the pfile/spfile. So that is not relevant for my answer. Yes, you should set the control file to point to where you want in the pfile/spfile.